# IPv6 reassembling

Tags: ipv6, ip-fragmentation

[RFC8200](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8200#section-4.5) specifically says that fragmentation is done only by the source node and not by any intermediate node.  It also says that fragments are reassembled at the receiver. Can I conclude from this that reassembly is done *only* at the receiver and no node other than the destination can reassemble packets?

Comment: The link you've given doesn't seem to link to a very helpful part of the standard. Could you edit it to point to the part of the standard that talks directly about fragmentation and reassembly?

Comment: Even with IPv4, reassembly is only supposed to happen at the receiver. In any case, many, many firewalls and routers disallow fragments because they can be used in attacks. _[RFC 791, Internet Protocol, Section 3.2 Discussion](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc791)_: "_The basic internet service is datagram oriented and provides for the fragmentation of datagrams at gateways, with reassembly taking place at the destination internet protocol module in the destination host._"

Answer (score 5):

Section 4.5 says, in part:

> (Note: unlike IPv4, fragmentation in IPv6 is performed only by source nodes, not by routers along a packet's delivery path -- see Section 5.)

Note that "no router can reassemble packets" isn't *strictly* true, and isn't *strictly* prohibited. Some firewalls will reassemble IPv6 fragments in memory in order to process them correctly, for instance; if they didn't reassemble them, they [wouldn't always be able to determine](https://serverfault.com/q/533704/126632) whether the traffic should be passed or blocked. But generally a router won't reassemble packets.

This is really all the answer that there is to your given question, though I *suspect* you have more questions or want more details about this than you've actually posted.

As a general rule, we really don't want to see fragmentation on the Internet; see [RFC 8201](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8201) for an explanation of Path MTU Discovery, which lets us avoid fragmentation. See also [Fragmentation Considered Harmful](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/Compaq-DEC/WRL-87-3.pdf) from 1987, [Fragmentation Considered Very Harmful](https://www.ietf.org/proceedings/66/slides/tsvarea-1.pdf) from 2006, and [How bad is ip fragmentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28476484/1068283) from right here on SO.